# Snake body rendering (body doesn't follow the head)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For some practice, I decided to make a snake game. But there's one problem: if you eat a fruit, it won't add a body part to the snake!(l 41 and further) I have a canvas so don't worry about that and I will optimize my code later. I know there are other ways to do it but I did it like this and I need your help to fix the issue. So when you eat a fruit, it is supposed to add a body part but instead it shrinks one and adds one so it stays the same. (exept the first time, then it add one!) I don't know why it works the first time and not for the other times. If you want to test, copy the code and add this HTML line to it:(with html tags!!!)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d"); //get the canvas
var WIDTH = 600;
var HEIGHT = 600;
var framecount = 0;
var fruitList = {};
var bodyparts = {};
var bodyparts2 = {};
var score = 0;
var bodyLenght = 1;
var bodyLenght2 = 0;
ctx.font = '30px Arial';
var head = { //head of snake
  x: 300,
  y: 300,
  spdX: 10,
  spdY: 5,
  color: 'blue',
  width: 20,
  lastX: 0,
  lastY: 0,
};
var body1 = {
  x: 300,
  y: 320,
  color: 'blue',
  width: 20,
  lastX: null,
  lastY: null,
}
var tail = {
  x: 300,
  y: 340,
  color: 'blue',
  width: 20,
  lastX: null,
  lastY: null,

}
bodyparts[1] = body1;
bodyparts2[1] = tail;
Body = function() { // snake's body
  var body = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    id: bodyLenght,
    color: 'blue',
    width: 20,
    lastX: null,
    lastY: null,
  };
  bodyparts[bodyLenght] = body;
  bodyparts2[bodyLenght2] = body;
}
Fruit = function(id, x, y, color) { // fruits 
  var fruit = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    id: id,
    color: 'orange',
    width: 20,
  };
  fruitList[id] = fruit;
}
setbodyPos = function(id1, id2) {
  id1.lastX = id1.x;
  id2.x = id1.lastX;
  id1.lastY = id1.y;
  id2.y = id1.lastY;
}
randomFruit = function() { // random coordinates for fruit
  var x = Math.random() * (WIDTH - 20);
  var y = Math.random() * (HEIGHT - 20);
  var id = Math.random;
  Fruit(id, x, y);
}
testCollisionRectRect = function(rect1, rect2) {
  return rect1.x <= rect2.x + rect2.width && rect2.x <= rect1.x + rect1.width && rect1.y <= rect2.y + rect2.width && rect2.y <= rect1.y + rect1.width;
}
updatePosition = function() {
  document.onkeydown = function(event) { //check if key is pressed
    if (event.keyCode === 68) //d
      head.pressingRight = true;
    else if (event.keyCode === 83) //s
      head.pressingDown = true;
    else if (event.keyCode === 81) //q
      head.pressingLeft = true;
    else if (event.keyCode === 90) // z
      head.pressingUp = true;
  }
  if (head.pressingRight) { //move head
    setbodyPos(bodyparts[bodyLenght], tail);
    for (var key in bodyparts) {
      for (var key2 in bodyparts2) {
        setbodyPos(bodyparts[key], bodyparts2[key2])
      }
    }
    setbodyPos(head, body1);
    head.x += head.width;
  }
  if (head.pressingLeft) {
    setbodyPos(bodyparts[bodyLenght], tail);
    for (var key in bodyparts) {
      for (var key2 in bodyparts2) {
        setbodyPos(bodyparts[key], bodyparts2[key2])
      }
    }
    setbodyPos(head, body1);
    head.x -= head.width;
  }
  if (head.pressingDown) {
    setbodyPos(bodyparts[bodyLenght], tail);
    for (var key in bodyparts) {
      for (var key2 in bodyparts2) {
        setbodyPos(bodyparts[key], bodyparts2[key2])
      }
    }
    setbodyPos(head, body1);
    head.y += head.width;
  }
  if (head.pressingUp) {
    setbodyPos(bodyparts[bodyLenght], tail);
    for (var key in bodyparts) {
      for (var key2 in bodyparts2) {
        setbodyPos(bodyparts[key], bodyparts2[key2])
      }
    }
    setbodyPos(head, body1);
    head.y -= head.width;
  }
  if (head.x > (WIDTH - head.width)) { // checks if it is a valid position
    head.x = WIDTH - head.width;
  };
  if (head.x < 0) {
    head.x = 0;
  };
  if (head.y > (HEIGHT - head.width)) {
    head.y = HEIGHT - head.width;
  };
  if (head.y < 0) {
    head.y = 0;
  };

  head.pressingDown = false; // no key is pressed
  head.pressingUp = false;
  head.pressingLeft = false;
  head.pressingRight = false;
}

drawEntity = function(id) { // draw rectangle in canvas
  ctx.save;
  ctx.fillStyle = id.color;
  ctx.fillRect(id.x, id.y, id.width, id.width);
  ctx.restore;
}

update = function() { //update canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  framecount++;
  if (framecount % 125 === 0) { // 5 sec
    randomFruit();
  }
  for (var key in fruitList) {
    drawEntity(fruitList[key]);
    if (testCollisionRectRect(head, fruitList[key]) === true) {
      delete fruitList[key];
      bodyLenght++;
      bodyLenght2++;
      Body();
      score++;
      tail.x = tail.lastX;
      tail.y = tail.lastY;
    };
  }
  updatePosition();
  drawEntity(head);
  drawEntity(tail);
  for (var key in bodyparts) {
    drawEntity(bodyparts[key]);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText('Score:' + score, 0, 30)
}

setInterval(update, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="ctx" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: First you should format your code properly. After that you should separate your data and logic from the view (drawing).

Comment: I did format it correctly in my file, just forgot to do it here

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here, so let me point you to a game I wrote to learn javascript years ago:

https://github.com/david0178418/Snake

Also, after I finished this, my coworker challenged me to turn it into a "worm" game.  The challenge was accepted:

https://github.com/david0178418/Worm

This is very old code (and when I was still a junior/mid level developer and entire js noob), but hopefully you can glean an answer from it.